# ASP.NET custom control, can template fields have attributes?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

For example:

```
<uc:AdmiralAckbar runat="server" id="myCustomControl">
<Warning SomeAttribute="It's A Trap">
My Data
</Warning>
</uc:AdmiralAckbar>
```

I'm not sure how to add SomeAttribute. Any ideas?

Code without the attribute is:

```
private ITemplate warning = null;

    [TemplateContainer(typeof(INamingContainer))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate Warning
    {
        get
        {
            return warning;
        }
        set
        {
            warning = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.

For this you should create a type which implements `ITemplate` interface and add a custom property/properties there (I added property `Name` in my example); also add a class which inherits from `Collection<YourTemplate>`.

Here is an example of doing that:

```
public class TemplateList : Collection<TemplateItem> { }

public class TemplateItem : ITemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.InnerText = this.Name;

        container.Controls.Add(div);
    }
}
```

and a control itself:

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Templates"), PersistChildren(false)]
public class TemplateLibrary : Control
{
    public TemplateLibrary()
    {
        Templates = new TemplateList();
    }

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public TemplateList Templates { get; set; }

    protected override void RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var item in Templates)
        {
            item.InstantiateIn(this);
        }

        base.RenderChildren(writer);
    }
}
```

and finally an example of usage:

```
<my:TemplateLibrary runat="server">
    <my:TemplateItem Name="hello" />
    <my:TemplateItem Name="there" />
</my:TemplateLibrary>
```

BTW, you could also use it as:

```
<my:TemplateLibrary runat="server">
    <Templates>
        <my:TemplateItem Name="hello" />
        <my:TemplateItem Name="there" />
    </Templates>
</my:TemplateLibrary>
```

the effect will be the same.

Comment: hi. when i try to inherit from itemplate i get a msg "class can inherit only from other classes" thanks

Comment: @Yisman, assume you're under `VB`, and should use `Implements` instead of `Inherits` (because this is an interface).

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but this code yields ITemplate objects (of said custom type) that *don't* have the Markup control tree built under them? Implementing a custom `InstantiateIn` sort of *defeats* the point of Markup templates ..