# Custom WebControl with templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates

I got this code which I wish to incorporate templates into. Nothing fancy, just adding some content to a specific place in the control

```
public class SiteTitle : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        CreateSiteTitle(writer);
    }

    private void CreateSiteTitle(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H3);
        writer.Write(this.Title);
        // RENDER THE HTML FROM THE TEMPLATE
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

I wish to use it like so:

```
<my:SiteTitle ID="SiteTitle1" runat="server" Title="Test Control">
    <RightContainer>
        <p>HTML</p>
    </RightContainer>
</my:SiteTitle>
```

I have tried messing with ITemplate and so, but I fail to do it. **Can someone provide an example on which I can work on?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719862%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Key method to implement here is InstantiateIn()...

Comment: Can you provide an example, I don't know how to incorporate it with my writer :/

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179599/asp-net-custom-control-can-template-fields-have-attributes